# how can I put a splash screen on my project using EGFLS in Qt/QML

Tags: qt, qml, splash-screen

I am new to Qt QML and trying to implement a splash screen in qml.
But, I am ended with below error when running the ui in eglfs instance.
"EGLFS: OpenGL windows cannot be mixed with others."
I have referred the below code from GIT and it was working good in x86 instance
Could you please help me in resolving this.

**main.qml**

```
Item {
Loader {
    id: mainWindowLoader
    anchors.fill: parent
    visible: false
    source: "qrc:/window.qml"
    asynchronous: true
    onLoaded: {
        item.visible = true;
        splashScreenLoader.item.visible = false;
        splashScreenLoader.source = "";
    }
}

Loader {
    id: splashScreenLoader
    source: "qrc:/splashscreen.qml"
    anchors.fill: parent
    asynchronous: false
    onLoaded: {
        mainWindowLoader.active = true;
    }
}
```

}

**spalshscreen.qml**

```
Window {
id: splashScreen
modality: Qt.ApplicationModal
flags: Qt.SplashScreen
width: 1024
height: 600

Rectangle {
    id: splashRect
    anchors.fill: parent
        color: "white"
    border.width: 1
    border.color: "black"
    
    Text {
        id: initializationErrorMessage
        text: "This is the splash screen"
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.top: parent.top
                   anchors.topMargin: 50
        font.bold: true
        font.pixelSize: 20
        color: "black"
    }
}
Component.onCompleted: visible = true
```

}

**window.qml**

```
ApplicationWindow {
id: mainWindow
flags: Qt.Window | Qt.WindowTitleHint | Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint | Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint
width: 1024
height: 600
visible: false
title: "Scresh Screen Test"

Component.onCompleted: {
    var timeout = new Date().valueOf() + 3000;
    while(timeout > new Date().valueOf()) {}
}

Text {
    text: "Window ready!"
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    font.bold: true
    font.pixelSize: 20
    color: "black"
}
```

}

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Please add to your question the contents of main.cpp.

Comment: The documentation here indicates EGLFS only supports one window. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html#eglfs